# Python Matrix without numpy

Tags: python, list, matrix

matrix = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,0,9]

find the index (column,row) of the largest element in a matrix. I can not use numpy. max() will not show the right location. Any thoughts on how to do this? I have looked every where for an answer
Edit :
max() only ids the largest list which in this case would be 1.
it will not compare the elements of each list to find the largest element

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find online, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1):

you can definitely use numpy for this..

```
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,0,9]])
print(matrix.max())
```

output:

```
9 #this is the max element in the array
```

to find the index (row,col) of the max element, use this:

```
loc = np.where(matrix == matrix.max())
print(loc)
```

output:

```
(array([2]), array([2]))

print(matrix[loc])
```

output:

```
[9]
```

if in fact you do not want to use np at all...you can do this:

```
x = matrix[0][0]
id = [0,0]
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        if matrix[i][j] > x:
            x = matrix[i][j]
            id = [i,j]

print(id)
[2,2]
```

i refers to the ith list in the matrix, j refers to the jth element in the ith list

Comment: I can not use numpy for this solution. That is a constraint of the question.

Comment: it was unclear as to whether this was a constraint of the question or not...you said you couldn't use np.max because it wouldnt work the way you want, and I showed you np does work...if you need a non np solution you should clarify the wording in your post

Comment: What if the matrix only has negative values? Then this will fail and not return anything. To fix this initialize x to matrix[0][0] rather than 0 and also initialize id to [0,0]. If matrix[0][0] is the max then it will give the correct result and if it is not then the true max and its location will be found within the loops.